# Why can't you use dot notation when accessing information from CSV row object?

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-csv

I am trying to loop through a CSV file and print out information from the rows. I have two columns with headers "description" and "status". If I loop through the CSV file, I get a series of `<CSV::Row "description":<description> "status":<status>` objects. I can access the info by using `csv_row["description"]`, but not `csv_row.description`. Since Ruby is creating objects out of the information on each line, why isn't it accessible with dot notation?

Sample code:

```
CSV.foreach(@file.path, headers:true) do |task|
    check_box = task["status"] == 0 ? "[ ] " : "[X] "
    puts check_box + task["description"]
end
```

Comment: Why would you expect an arbitrary class (`CSV::Row` in this case) to respond to an arbitrary method of your choice (`description`)? This class author had implemented `#[]` method and did not bother to implement all the accessors.

Comment: _"why isn't it accessible with dot notation?"_ – conflicts between CSV headers and methods with the same name would arise.

Comment: @Stefan fwiw, this conflict does arise in the exact same way with hash-like access, does not it?

Comment: @mudasobwa what do you mean? `task['index']` refers to a header with name `index`, not to the [`CSV::Row#index`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-index) method. I see no conflict there.

Comment: @Stefan ah, I get it now. I thought you meant the case when method names collide because of two or more same headers in the input.

Answer (score 1):

`CSV` doesn't work that way but you could use [`OpenStruct`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html):

```
require 'ostruct'

CSV.foreach(@file.path, headers: true) do |row|
  task = OpenStruct.new(row.to_hash)
  check_box = task.status == '0' ? '[ ]' : '[X]'
  puts "#{check_box} #{task.description}"
end
```

Or just create a custom class that fits your needs, e.g. via [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Struct.html):

```
Task = Struct.new(:status, :description) do
  def checkbox
    status == 0 ? '[ ]' : '[X]'
  end

  def to_s
    "#{checkbox} #{description}"
  end
end

CSV_OPTIONS = { headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, converters: :numeric }
CSV.foreach(@file.path, CSV_OPTIONS) do |row|
  task = Task.new(row[:status], row[:description])
  puts task
end
```